# encrypt with mysql and decrypt with sqlite3?

Tags: android, mysql

i'm planning to create a web service to displays encrypted values. i then plan to create an android app to read this web service and download it to local database then decrypts it and displays it in List.

is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine the best way to do this would to insert the values from the website into the sqlite db and then decrypt them on the fly so that the data is not exposed if your phone is lost. However, the decryption process may take awhile and thus make the UX less than desirable. Hope that helps.